# Apollo GraphQL & Google Map

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, wrapper, apollo, mutation

I'm building a site using React & Apollo. I have a Google map with markers. The google-maps-react package requires that you wrap your class holding the map with the google maps wrapper, but each of my markers will have an InfoWindow which can have a edit / delete button. So ideally, I would like to also wrap this class with a graphQL mutation to delete one of the marker locations. I'm confused on how to do this. Here is my code:

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  //.........

  render() {
    if(this.props.loading){
      return <p>Loading map..</p>
    }

    let editDeleteBtns;
      //somelogic {
        editDeleteBtns = (
          <div>
            <button onClick={//do the onclick thing}>Edit</button>
            <button onClick={//do the other onclick thing}>Delete</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        onClick={this.onMapClicked}
        onReady={this.fetchPlaces}
        initialCenter={{lat:this.props.lat, lng:this.props.lng}}
        >
          {
            this.props.locations.map((location) => {
              return (<Marker key={location.googleId}
                location_id={location.id}
                title={location.title}
                name={location.title}
                createdBy={location.createdBy.id}
                position={{lat: location.loc.lat, lng: location.loc.lng}}
                onClick={this.onMarkerClick} />)
            })
          }

        <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
            <div>
              {
                editDeleteBtns
              }
              <h1>{this.state.activeMarker ? this.state.activeMarker.title: ''}</h1>
            </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey:'the thing you use to make google maps google'
})(MapContainer)
```

This is also my first time making a complete site using react, so it seems like I am doing something in a non-react way, I'd love anyones input on how I can improve what I'm doing (for example, should I make the edit/delete buttons a separate component, and wrap that new component class with my graphql mutation? Or is this too bloated of a map class, and the separation of concerns isn't being properly addressed)